# Geopandas: not able to change the crs of a geopandas object

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to set the `crs` of a geopandas object as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961816/geopandas-set-crs-on-points).

The example file can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_RLTI_uYMkhMzWpNdK7i7UxetKHeoT9/view?usp=sharing)

```
import geopandas as gdp
df = pd.read_pickle('myShp.pickle')
```

I upload the screenshot to show the values of the coordinates

[image]

then if I try to change the `crs` the values of the polygon don't change

```
tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
tmp.crs = {'init' :'epsg:32618'}
```

I show again the screenshot

[image]

If I try:

```
import geopandas as gdp
df = pd.read_pickle('myShp.pickle')
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
dfNew=df.to_crs(epsg=32618)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Cannot transform naive geometries.  Please set a crs on the object first.
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is not working? Is it raising an error if you try to change the crs with `to_crs` ?

Comment: @joris I modified the text. I don't receive an error but the values of the coordinates don't change

Comment: If your data has no CRS information, you first need to *set* (how you did it before) the CRS, but with the CRS your data is in, not the CRS you want to convert them to.

Comment: @joris now it seems to work. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `crs` like:

```
gdf.crs = {'init' :'epsg:32618'}
```

does not *transform* your data, it only sets the CRS (it basically says: "my data is represented in this CRS"). In most cases, the CRS is already set while reading the data with `geopandas.read_file` (if your file has CRS information). So you only need the above when your data has no CRS information yet.

If you actually want to convert the coordinates to a different CRS, you can use the [`to_crs`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs) method:

```
gdf_new = gdf.to_crs(epsg=32618)
```

See https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projections.html

Comment: Then please show that in your question (the code you tried, with the output). I don't see any `to_crs` call in your example code.

Comment: yes it is there. `tmp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
tmp.crs = {'init' :'epsg:32618'}`

Comment: Please read my answer and comment. You are using `tmp.crs = ...`, I am saying to use `tmp.to_crs(...)`.

Comment: please see the modified version  of my question

Answer (score 0):

super late answer, but it's:

```
tmp.set_crs(...)
```

Use this to define whatever coordinate system the data is in, i.e. 'telling the computer what coordinate system we started in'

Then;

```
tmp.to_crs(...)
```

Use this to change to your new preferred crs.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.