# problem with plotting the lat and lng to map(shp file)

Tags: python, geopandas

I am working with Asheville Airbnb dataset and want to plot the neighborhoods based on their lat and lng, but it won't map together!

```
shp_path = '../Airbnb_Asheville/Asheville_City_Limits/Asheville_City_Limits.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(shp_path)

geom2 = ashvile_list[['latitude', 'longitude','neighbourhood_cleansed','room_type']]
geom2 = geom2.rename(columns={'neighbourhood_cleansed': 'neighbourhood'})
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip (geom2["latitude"], geom2["longitude"])]

crs = {'init': 'epsg:3857'}
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geom2, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

fig, gax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
gdf.boundary.plot(ax=gax)
geo_df.plot(ax=gax, color='red', alpha = 0.5)

gax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
gax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
gax.set_title('Asheville Airbnb')

plt.show()
```

The result of above code:

[image]

here is the geo_df.head():

[image]

and gdf.head():

[image]

I am using this tutorial to do so: https://datascience.quantecon.org/applications/maps.html

Comment: Your two datasets are in different projections. Read the geopandas docs on managing projections and figure out what the crs of the two data sources are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Hey, so in general you have multiple problems here...

1. as initially mentioned your data is given in lon/lat so your crs is most probably epsg=4326 not epsg=3857 (also note its lon/lat not lat/lon !)
2. Looking at your data (from [here](https://github.com/sepideh68/Airbnb)), you are missing accompanying files to geolocate the shape (e.g. the spatial-index file `<filename>.shx` and the projection description `<filename>.prj`). I downloaded the shapefile **incl. all aux. files** from [here](https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/9fdb214ab6544f65b7493eeb5279ac0d_0/about).
3. since you use normal matplotlib axes, you need to handle reprojections manually! (e.g. you need to bring all your data and the shape in the same crs before you can put them on the same plot... (your data is in epsg=4326 but your shape is in epsg=2264) for GeoDataFrames you can use `gdf.to_crs(...)`)

I strongly recommend that you have a look at [cartopy](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy) or [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) and use projection-aware matplotlib axes to visualize your data!

... finally, here's how I would plot it using [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) :-)

```py
from eomaps import Maps
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# read the data (no need to manually specify crs if .prj and .shx files are available!)
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"Asheville_City_Limits\Asheville_City_Limits.shp")
data = pd.read_csv(r"Asheville_listings.csv")

m = Maps(crs=Maps.CRS.GOOGLE_MERCATOR, figsize=(6, 8))
m.add_gdf(gdf, fc="none", ec="darkblue", lw=2)

# plot the data
m.set_data(data, "longitude", "latitude", crs=4326, parameter="availability_365")
m.set_shape.scatter_points(size=5)
m.set_classify.EqualInterval(k=5)
m.plot_map(ec="k", lw=0.25)
m.add_colorbar(hist_bins=100, label="Availability 365")

# add a background map
m.add_wms.OpenStreetMap.add_layer.default(alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

---

**Old answer**

It's difficult to say without having access to the actual data, but from what I see you simply picked the wrong epsg code for your data!

[epsg 3857](https://epsg.io/3857) is a pseudo-mercator projection (with units of "meters") not lon/lat... you most probably want [epsg 4326](https://epsg.io/4326)!

e.g. since `geometry` is provided in lon/lat, the crs should be:

```
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

Comment: when I use the espg 4326 the map will shrink to the left side!

Comment: of course... because that's where you're coordinates really are! You should use a projection-aware axes (e.g. use [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/index.html#) or [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) to properly handle coordinate-projections... at the moment you plot your shapes and points as if they are in the same projection but they are not!   if you want to stick with a non-projection aware axes you need to handle reprojections yourself (use `gdf.to_crs(....)` before plotting)

Comment: Is there any way I share my code with you? I still didn't figure out how to solve this issue! I have tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961816/geopandas-set-crs-on-points too but still got the same problem!

Comment: hey, its not so much the code... its the data I would need to pinpoint your issue... if you upload it somewhere and share the link I can have a look (a subset is also fine if its a large dataset).

Comment: I have uploaded them to my github: https://github.com/sepideh68/Airbnb I appreciate if you have time to look at it. Thanks.

Comment: hey @Sepid,  check my updates for the answer!